# Kendo AutoComplete - Set Cursor at beginning of autocompleted text

Tags: jquery, css, kendo-ui, autocomplete, focus

Please see this example

https://dojo.telerik.com/IxeruLIH/2

When I use the autocomplete feature to select the value: "Super Long Country Name That Wont Fit In Box", i get the following behaviors from browsers:

Chrome: By default, the beginning of the text is displayed (Good).

Internet Explorer: By default, the end of the text is displayed (Bad), but I was able to fix with the focus() and setSelectionRange() calls in the select event handler.

Firefox: By default, the end of the text is displayed (Bad), and I can't find anything to fix in this situation.

Does anyone have any ideas how I can fix this in Firefox?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue relays on the delay to close the popup window suggestion.

You may consider to wait a few milliseconds before running your code. If you pay attention the issue is also for chrome and ie.

```
select: function (e) {
    setTimeout(function () {
        $("#countries").focus();
        $("#countries")[0].setSelectionRange(0, 0);
    }, 100);
}
```

```js
var data = [
    "Austria",
    "Azerbaijan",
    "Super Long Country Name That Wont Fit In Box",
    "Ukraine",
];

$("#countries").kendoAutoComplete({
    dataSource: data,
    placeholder: "Select country...",
    separator: ", ",
    select: function (e) {
        setTimeout(function () {
            $("#countries").focus();
            $("#countries")[0].setSelectionRange(0, 0);
        }, 100);
    }
});
```

```css
html {
    font-size: 14px;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2018.3.1017/styles/kendo.common-material.min.css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2018.3.1017/styles/kendo.material.min.css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2018.3.1017/styles/kendo.material.mobile.min.css"/>

<script src="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2018.3.1017/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2018.3.1017/js/kendo.all.min.js"></script>


<div id="example">
    <input id="countries" style="width: 200px;"/>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you sir, adding the delay fixes the issue in Firefox!